# Standard way for MapReduce development in Windows Dev and Linux Deployment Environment

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a complete newbie in Java/Linux/Hadoop environment. So I have a very basic question that I am struggling with and need some help from the community. I have been trying to write a couple of Map Reduce programs using Eclipse and Hadoop 2.0. I have a windows machine with Eclipse Neon as my dev environment. I am able to write the MR program, add the Hadoop jars as external references in Eclipse and successfully compile and create the runnable jar file. I have Hadoop setup in an Oracle VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to run the jar file using the Hadoop commandline client in the VM box but getting different errors like ClassDefNotFound, etc. I think it could be an issue with the fact that the Hadoop dependency jar locations are different in the dev and deployment environment. So do I need to explicitly compile the java class files in the linux box and then run the jar file.
A couple of more generic questions arising from the above point are:

1. What is the professional or standard way to do Java MapReduce development in a windows box and then deploy in a linux environment?
2. People have suggested Maven, but I wanted to learn the industry standard practice for environments which do not have Maven. And Maven would again be a learning curve for me. So just thought of learning the steps to do it with vanilla java and eclipse.
3. Are there any standard traditional ways to do Debugging and/or troubleshooting for Java MapReduce in case of a Windows Dev and Linux Deploy environment.

I know these questions are probably very basic but I would really need to get this into a well defined and standard process before I explore further. Some basic explanation along with relevant links might also be good as I have time to read.

Comment: Hi...make sure java version is same in linux and windows just in case if you want to refer map reduce example please refer http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/12/poc-sensex-log-data-processing-pdf-file.html